FYI: Ethereum.SE proposal on the way on Area 51
For those of you interested in Ethereum, there is a proposal for an Ethereum.SE in the commitment phase.
Also check out our questions tagged ethereum. 

Update: The Ethereum proposal has reached 100% commitment, and will be starting into beta soon.
Moar Update: Private Beta has commenced.
